# Практика вставки данных через временные таблицы

Tags: mysql

Доброго дня.

Структура БД такова, что необходимо воткнуть данные в четыре таблицы. Порядка 20 строк в сумме, дважды отлавливать `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Операция нечастая. Есть два варианта: либо реализовать транзакцию, либо записывать данные во временные таблицы и вызывать хранимую процедуру. Последний вариант мне кажется проще, меньше кода в самом приложении. Но смущает, что реализован он будет для небольших объемов данных.
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, личным опытом. Является ли использование временных таблиц для рутинной вставки данных нормальной практикой, или это скорее сляпанный на коленке подход, чтобы заткнуть дыры в проектировании.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Временные таблицы обычно используются при массивной либо нетривиальной работе с БД, для того, чтобы понять, какой именно способ лучше в вашем случае - недостаточно информации.

В любом случае, если таки будете работать с временными таблицами, не забывайте использовать движок `memory`.

Comment: Спасибо. В принципе, я так и думал. Если можно сравнительно легко обойтись без временной таблицы - надо обходиться без нее.